# PHP: Proper way of using a PDO database connection in a class

Tags: php, oop

Trying to organize all my code into classes, and I can't get the database queries to work inside a class. I tested it without the class wrapper, and it worked fine. Inside the class = no dice. **What about my classes is messing this up?**

**EDIT:** The problem is that it won't query the database and return a result. Any result.

```
class ac
  {
  public function dbConnect() 
    {
    global $dbcon;

    $dbInfo['server'] = "localhost";
    $dbInfo['database'] = "sn";
    $dbInfo['username'] = "sn";
    $dbInfo['password'] = "password"; 

    $con = "mysql:host=" . $dbInfo['server'] . "; dbname=" . $dbInfo['database'];
    $dbcon = new PDO($con, $dbInfo['username'], $dbInfo['password']);
    $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $error = $dbcon->errorInfo();

    if($error[0] != "") 
      {
      print "<p>DATABASE CONNECTION ERROR:</p>";
      print_r($error);
      }
    }


  public function authentication()
    {
    global $dbcon;

    $plain_username = $_POST['username'];
    $md5_password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $ac = new ac();
    if (is_int($ac->check_credentials($plain_username, $md5_password)))
      {
      ?>
      <p>Welcome!</p> <!--go to account manager here-->
      <?php
      }
    else
      {
      ?>
      <p>Not a valid username and/or password. Please try again.</p>
      <?php
      unset($_POST['username']);
      unset($_POST['password']);
      $ui = new ui();
      $ui->start();
      }
    }



  private function check_credentials($plain_username, $md5_password)
    {
    global $dbcon;

    $userid = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1');
    $userid->bindParam(':username', $plain_username);
    $userid->bindParam(':password', $md5_password);
    $userid->execute();

    print_r($dbcon->errorInfo());

    $id = $userid->fetch();
    Return $id;
    }
  }
```

And if it's any help, here's the class that's calling it:

```
require_once("ac/acclass.php");
$ac = new ac();
$ac->dbconnect();
class ui
  {
  public function start()
    {
    if ((!isset($_POST['username'])) && (!isset($_POST['password'])))
      {
      $ui = new ui();
      $ui->loginform();
      }
    else
      {
      $ac = new ac();
      $ac->authentication();
      }
    }

  private function loginform()
    {
    ?>
    <form id="userlogin" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
     User:<input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
     Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you define *not working*?

Comment: No results return from the query

Comment: do you mean the query fails (i.e. produces an error) or that the query succeeds but the result set is empty?

Comment: Not sure. I don't get any error, but nothing is returned. I've gone so far as to place the username and password right in the query, and I still get no matches

Comment: if there's an error, the statement should throw a PDOException, and set `PDOStatement::errorCode` and `PDOStatement::errorInfo`. If there's simply an empty result set (meaning the query succeeded with no matches), `PDOStatement::rowCount` should return 0 with MySQL (however, see the doc http://php.net/PDOStatement.rowCount) and the `PDOStatement::fetch*` methods will return `False`.

Comment: There is a whole lot "wrong" with this code. Classes are not meant to be namespaces to hold functions that operate on global data, but rather encapsulated data and a (minimal) set of methods to operate on that. methods should not access global data, like $_GET, $_POST, etc. but instead accept the data that is not intrinsic to the class as arguments, You should probably use exceptions for error handling instead of echoing to the browser, It's probably a bad idea to ever toggle out of php mode inside a class definition. On the upside though, you're using PDO, you're already miles ahead of most!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default for `PDOStatement::fetch` is to return a row as an array of fields, indexed by column name and number (mode `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`). This means `ac::check_credentials` returns an array, but `ac::authentication` checks for an integer. Also, field values are strings, so `is_int` will fail unless you explicitly convert the result field to an integer. Try [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) and [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric).

```
    public function authentication() {
        ...
        if (is_numeric($this->check_credentials($plain_username, $md5_password))) {
        ...
    }

    private function check_credentials($plain_username, $md5_password) {
        return $userid->fetchColumn();
    }
```

As an alternative to `is_numeric`, check that the result of the credential check isn't identical to `False`.

```
    public function authentication() {
        ...
        if (False !== $this->check_credentials($plain_username, $md5_password)) {
        ...
    }
```

#### Some [Stylistic](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+style+guide) Points

As Yaggo points out, `ui::start` and `ac::dbConnect` should be static methods. `ac::authentication` doesn't need to create a new `ac`; since it's not a static method, it can access the current object via the `$this` special variable (as is done above).  `$dbcon` should be made a static property of `ac` so you don't [pollute the global namespace](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Class names should use [UpperCamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), and should be more descriptive.

Classes should have a single, well-defined purpose and not stray from that. `ac` has many purposes: manage a DB connection, handle authentication and display results of authentication. Consider designing a set of classes for a Data Access Layer, hiding the database from everything else. Also consider separating the domain logic (authentication &c) from display. This is part of the pattern known as the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture. This doesn't need to happen all at once; you can slowly refactor the code.

Comment: +1 + FYI: `UpperCamelCase` has a "real" name too: `PascalCase`. which is not `camelCase`

Answer (score 1):

Won't solve your problem, but if you are using the classes just as namespaces to group similar functions together, consider using static methods to avoid the overhead of creating an instance.

```
class Foo {

    static function bar() {

    }

}

Foo::bar()
```